# Passing a DataFrame column as argument to a function

Tags: r

I use Windows and R 3.5.0

I am a beginner and have a problem with a basic code. I have defined a function which takes 3 arguments - **findmean("path", "variable", id)**. The data frame has several columns and I have to find the mean of one of the columns. When I find the mean of the "AGE" column using

```
mean(finaldata$AGE,na.rm=TRUE)
```

and run

```
findmean("path", id = 1: 5)
```

i get the correct mean, but when i change it to

```
mean(finaldata$variable, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and run

```
findmean("path", "AGE", id = 1:5)
```

I am getting an error: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

Please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `finaldata[[variable]]`  Not clear what `path` and `id` signifies in the `mean` Are you subsetting based on 'id's?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `findmean` function that you cannot do with just the `mean` function?  Can you post the function?

Comment: I think your title should be *"How to pass a string as argument to a function?"* or better still *"How to select a dataframe column with a string variable name?"*

Comment: @akrun It worked. Thank you.